# Selection into DataTable as a Cell

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, system.data

What is the best way to get a specific [Column][Row] value into a DataTable ?

```
    private DataTable CurrentTable { get; set; }
    public string selectCell(int Column, int Row)
    {
        return CurrentTable............
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate indexer:

```
public string selectCell(int Column, int Row)
{
    if (CurrentTable.Rows.Count <= Row)   // zero based indices
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of rows in selectCell", "Row");
    if (CurrentTable.Columns.Count <= Column)
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid number of columns in selectCell", "Column");
    var row = CurrentTable.Rows[Row];
    // remove following  check if you want to return "" instead of null
    // but then you won't know if it was an empty or an undefined value
    if (row.IsNull(Column))  
        return null;
    return row[Column].ToString();
}
```

You could also use the typed [`Field` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) which also supports nullable types, but since you want to use this method for all fields it's better to use `Object.ToString` as shown above.